# Working with PHP script on the fly during single AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, image-uploading

I'm new into this, so please be forgiving. And what's funny actually I don't know how to ask my question to be honest, so I'm sorry if it's not clear at all...

I was wondering if it's possible to, for example modify some variables with user input in PHP script triggered by AJAX during that AJAX.

To be specific, I'm thinking about script for uploading files - first it's checking if the file already exist, and then (if it does) asks user what to do, replace, rename, or die. I imagine that this would be possible with two queries, and two scripts, but maybe there is some better and cleaner way to do this?

As I mentioned, I'm quite new with scripting, and I don't fully understand how XHR, and AJAX and all of that works, so even some generic guides that will help me to dig into this would be very desirable.

Comment: no. that'd require multiple requests. an http request is request->response, not request->query->interrogation->confirmation->response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible to do in a single ajax request.So for your example you should have the following ajax requests

1. check if the file exists
2. Ask the user what to do

Now for making script a little cleaner have a look at the following codes

```
<?php
$command = $_POST["command"];
//$command stores the name of function code that you need to process
$command();
?>
```

The codes above are just a suggestion you can implement the codes in many other ways also

Comment: Just a note: you really should verify that `$command` contains an allowed value before executing it. Executing a server-side function based on data from a client without sanitizing it is a security flaw.